# Put quotes around individual elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings of length in hundreds. Unfortunately, I forgot to put quotes around each element while creating it manually. Is it possible to put these quotes by using a single command instead of doing it manually in R/RStudio?

## Example string:

```
c(122.3.Car, 125.1.Car, 132.3.Car, 140.2.Car, 163.2.Car)
```

## Expected output:

```
c("122.3.Car", "125.1.Car", "132.3.Car", "140.2.Car", "163.2.Car")
```

Comment: How sure are you that there are no extra comma in the values themselves? Also, how have you read the string into R? Is your example string in an R variable? In a text file?

Comment: 100% sure that there is no extra comma in the values. I haven't read the string; instead just typed it while I was gathering info from an experiment. So, it is not an R variable. Not in a text file but I can save it in one.

Comment: Maybe find and replace `,` with `","` ? How many such strings do you have, are they in a text file, did you put `c(` at the beginning manually? I think you should mention what are you planning to do with expected output, maybe it is better to transform it into a data.frame?

Comment: Thanks zx8754, I replaced `,` with `","` but that left a space on the left of every string. I read that as a string vector in R and used `str_trim` of `stringr` package to remove spaces. Saved a lot of time!

Comment: *instead just typed it*? Then you need general help regarding RStudio. You might find help on Superuser and not here. And I guess you need to find and replace `, ​` (comma with space - Guess markdown has ignored @zx8754's space there) with `", "`.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Yes, resolved. Thanks everyone.